# Facebook Chat, XMPP, Setting presence?

Tags: facebook, xmpp, facebook-chat

When changing the presence in Browser (offline/online) in Facebook Chat, the chat system sends the XMPP message in form:

```
<presence to="-myidhere@chat.facebook.com/adfskjfskjdfh" from="-otheridhere@chat.facebook.com" type="unavailable">
```

When I send my own presence from non-browser side (xmpp client) to the browser side with exactly same syntax, it seem not to effect. What I am missing here ?

Thanks a lot,
    -Mika

Comment: What do you mean? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Managed not to escape my XML, sorry. Anyways I do have own XMPP client which I want to use to send <presence from="myownclient" to="chat client through browser" type="unavailable"> so the Facebook side browser chat client would notice my own chat client to be unavailable.

Comment: I see. And do you get an error when sending this presence or it's just ignored?

Comment: I do not get any response from the server side. I am using same jid(s) for sending chat status stanzas and also messages which seem to work nicely, just the presence has problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can't do that with the facebook xmpp implementation, as they write in the documentation:

> Facebook Chat should be compatible with every XMPP client, but is not
>   a full XMPP server. It should be thought of as a proxy into the world
>   of Facebook Chat on www.facebook.com. As a result, it has several
>   behaviors that differ slightly from what you would expect from a
>   traditional XMPP service

There's an open bug on this matter: [XMPP: can't change availability](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/370966862930215), and also this thread also talks about it: [Xmpp chat invisible presence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141155/xmpp-chat-invisible-presence).

Also, don't expect the fb apis to have the same functionality as you get using the fb webpage.
They obviously don't open everything they have to the apis.

Comment: I checked as well the Chat API documentation and feared that the presence part is not working both ways same kind. Need to think some other ways to accomplish same effect somehow. Thanks a lot for answer!